# how to search an array of hashes for values that are in-between two other values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array of hashes in the following format:

s[0]= {:address=>"121 testing rd", :locality=>"Clarington", :neighbourhood=>"Newcastle", :lot_front=>19.0, :lot_depth=>46.0, :property_type=>"Detached", :closed_price=>1000000, :sold_date=>"02/04/2005"}

I am trying to file the items in the array that have sold between certain dates and between certain lot_front and lot_depths.

Ie, find all properties sold between 01/01/2000 and 01/01/2020 and that have a lot_front of between 0 and 100 and a lot_depth between 0 and 100.

Is there similar code to s.select { |i| i[:locality] = "clarington"} but instead of the "=" using something that will allow me to input the max and min values and get a return of any value in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ranges and the `cover?` method to find the records:

```
dates = Date.parse('01/01/2000')..Date.parse('01/01/2020')
depth = 1..100

a.select do |h| 
  dates.cover?(h[:sold_date].to_date) && depth.cover?(h[:lot_depth]) && depth.cover?(h[:lot_front])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use `>` and `<` and combine it with an `&&` (and).

```
array.select do |element|
  element[:lot_depth] > 1 &&
    element[:lot_front] < 3
end
```

If you want to have it inclusive you can use `<=` and >=` of course.